# C3P0 datasource opens many threads to manage

Tags: c3p0

C3P0 datasource opens many threads to manage the connections in application. Is there a way where will it open only single thread for all the opened datasources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. c3p0 requires a Thread pool in order to perform Connection maintenance tasks without blocking client Threads.